# Unresolved dependencies: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I downloaded Android Studio for the first time and encountered a problem:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

On a another dock appeared:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Where and how can I resolved the issue?

I believe the error is with constraint-layout:1.0.1 but I can't seem to find solution else where.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to internet and sync project with gradle and gradle will download neccessary files.if you have problem to connect to the internet to download gradle, you can set http proxy this way :

File->Settings->search for Proxy->select Manual proxy configuration->HTTP
Host name:[yourHost] Port number:[yourPort]

you need to change the Host name to the proxy you use

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

It's probably because incompatibility with the recent Android Studio. You can try using version 1.0.2 with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

don't forget to add the `google()` maven to your `build.gradle`.

See the artifacts at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support.constraint/constraint-layout

But, you should consider upgrading your project to AndroidX. See Migrating to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).